# Css transitions very choppy

Tags: css

I'm just not sure why these transitions are so laggy.I've never had this happen to me before.
My code is:

```
 <section class='containgrid'>
    <div class="grid">         
      <div class="unit one-third">
        <div class="eventbox">
                 <img class='imgfit' src='images/choice1.jpg'/>               
        <h2 class='contactheading'>Questions?</h2>
        <h3 id='subheading'>subheading</h3>         
            </div>     
     </div>
     </div>
          </section>
```

Not shown is 2 more "unit one-third"s, I took them out for clarity but the other two are the exact same as the first one. As you can tell I'm using gridism for a simple grid layout, my relevant css code is so:

```
.imgfit{
    width:98%;
    margin:.2em;
    height:375px;
}
.eventbox{
    background-color:#F1EFEF;
    margin-top:15%;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s;
    -moz-transition:  background-color 0.3s;
    transition:  background-color 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: border 0.3s;
    -moz-transition:  border 0.3s;
    transition:  border 0.3s;
    border:solid #F1EFEF .2em;
}
.eventbox:hover{
    background-color:#DBDBDB;
    border:solid #7D7D7D .2em;

}
```

This seems really straightforward to me, but when I open it up in browser it becomes really laggy and is not smooth at all.Why?

Comment: I put the above in JSFiddle & it works just fine for me in both Chrome & Firefox. Transitions are smoothly animating. Maybe something about the grid framework or some other dependency?

Comment: Animations (no matter which technology is used) are always depandant on the machine they're executed on. Make sure you have current hardware and drivers, also try different browsers.

Comment: my computer is definitely good enough to do transitions like these (clevo w230st) I will see if removing other elements improves the responsiveness

Comment: ok... after multiple refreshing... I've discovered that sometimes when you refresh the css is fast and other time it is slow, what could this mean?